# GNU Octave error message

Tags: octave

When I load Octave each time I get the below errors after the welcome/info message.

```
error: `prefix' undefined near line 12 column 35

error: evaluating argument list element number 2

error: called from:

error:   C:\Octave\Octave3.4.3_gcc4.5.2\share\octave\site\m\startup/octaverc at line 12, column 1

octave:1>
```

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: A way to find out would be to look at line 12 of the file mentioned in the error message. Besides, is it really octave3.4.3 ? This is really old...

Answer (score 0):

For that version of octave, the default settings of that file around that line are:

```
prefix=octave_config_info('prefix');
setenv('path',[getenv('path'),';',prefix,'\mingw32\bin;',prefix,'\msys\bin']);
setenv('path',[getenv('path'),';',prefix,'\gs\gs9.02\bin'])
```

So you should check if it has changed